# Grammar of "supposed to": part of speech / word class, active or passive?

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

If I say

> I'm supposed to go.

Is *supposed to* here an adjective in a passive construction?

Answer (score 4):

Historically, *supposed* is indeed a past participle, and *am supposed* is a passive.

But it is not helpful to think of it this way, because the meaning of the adjectival phrase *supposed to* cannot be derived from the verb *suppose*.

*Supposed to* means "ought to", or "expected to", but we can't say *I suppose him to go* in that sense.

The verb *suppose* means something like "guess", or (in more formal contexts) "assume for current purposes": there is no sense of obligation in it.

Comment: The meaning can indeed be derived from the verb **supposed**. The derivation simply requires one to understand that those who are doing the supposing (the omitted actors ) are the community at large, the consensus shaping the individual's sense of moral obligation.  There is a difference between *must* and and **ought* and **supposed to**. **Must** and **ought** express necessity or a proper action, whereas **supposed to** conveys the idea that "this is what {people in general, or specific people} expect of me*.  "

Comment: "I'm supposed to watch my little brother" usually means "my parents expect me to watch my little brother" although it could mean "Everyone expects big brothers to watch out for their younger siblings"

Comment: The trouble with that argument is that there is no "X supposes me to watch my little brother" with that meaning, whatever the value of X.

Comment: Ah, but there **is** indeed the transitive use of the verb where the direct object is complemented by an infinitive clause, where the direct object is believed to possess a quality or to do a thing. *They suppose him to be coaching the team.*  The passive of that: *He is supposed to be coaching the team.*  When that same verb is used *by the person about whom the supposition is made*, and is put in the passive, it accrues (or can accrue) a sense of duty or obligation. *I am supposed to be coaching the team, not gambling on the game's outcome.*

Comment: When it is used in the active voice, the statement is about *them* and their supposition, not about the speaker and his or her duty: *They suppose me to be coaching the team, when I am actually gambling on the game's outcome.*

Comment: "When that same verb is used by the person about whom the supposition is made, and is put in the passive, it accrues (or can accrue) a sense of duty or obligation." I think that accrual (sc. extension of meaning) is the bit I was referring to when I said the phrase could not be derived from the verb.

Comment: Whence cometh the adjective then?

Comment: _Diachronically_ it no doubt came from an application of the verb. My statement was obviously meant syncrhonically.

Answer (score 0):

**supposed to** expresses a duty or a requirement.
Consider the following sentence:

> A big brother is supposed to protect his little brother.

Because it is expressed in the passive voice, those who suppose are absent from the sentence; they are not specific individuals but "everyone". The general opinion is that a big brother should watch over his little brother. Everyone expects an older brother to protect his younger brother. This expectation is understood by the individual as a *duty*.

**A big brother's duty is to protect his little brother.**

Now consider these sentences:

I told my father that I would drive him to the train station. He is supposed to be there by 8AM.

**He is supposed to be there by 8AM.**

Clearly this is not the same sort of duty that we saw with big brother/little brother.  Here it means, he *is required* to arrive no later than 8AM, presumably because the train leaves shortly thereafter.  It is a general requirement, and so those who require are not relevant. The passive is a good choice for such situations.

When **suppose** is used in the active voice, there is no sense of duty or requirement. In the active voice, it means "to believe" or "to expect".

**The military commander supposed the enemy to be in a weakened condition; he thought they had not eaten for several days and were low on ammunition.**

P.S. As I state in my comment to Colin, it is indeed helpful to understand **supposed to** as a passive construction. There is a significant difference between **must** and **supposed to**, both of which can be used to express obligation. The phrase **supposed to** refers tacitly to *the expectations of others*. These others are the unstated actors in the passive construction. They can be parents or guardians:

> I'm supposed to watch my little brother today.

or society at large:

> A big brother is supposed to watch his little brother.

When a native speaker says "I'm supposed to watch my little brother today" he or she is basically saying "*I've been told* (by my parents) that I must watch my little brother today" or something close to that. With **supposed to** and **expected to**, the presence of some unnamed *others* is felt more strongly than it is with **must**. Cognitively, when we refer to "expectations", there is an implicit underlying reference to those who have these expectations, inasmuch as expectations do not exist except in the minds of those who have them.

Now, you might want to call **supposed to ...** or **expected to ...** adjectives complemented by a to-infinitive clause. That is far more twisted, IMO, than calling it a passive construction understanding the unstated actors in the passive construction as *unnamed other(s)*—anyone who can give us commands or cause us to feel obliged to do something, whether they be peers, spouses, bosses and supervisors, colleagues, community, or just people in general.

Comment: I would like an explanation of the downvotes, please.