# 'suppose' and 'think' in passive voice

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I came across this task during my exam.

> Ted Sanford was born nine minutes later than his brother Harry. It was his twin brother, Harry, who was (**supposed/thought**) to become an earl, to inherit a castle in Scotland.

I had a feeling that **supposed** was the right answer and it was indeed, but I can't explain to myself why **thought** isn't correct. Could you, please, help me with that?

I think this is in passive voice because here it is said that constructions with 'supposed' belong to Passive Voice. https://learn-english.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-passive-voice-supposed-english-234202/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1: *Harry **was supposed to** become an earl*
>    =
>    ***It was intended*** that Harry should become an earl

This is a special use of the verb ***to suppose*** that only occurs in passive contexts (where the actual "agent" doing the "supposing" is unspecified). But hopefully you can see how the more common meaning ***to suppose = assume / think / guess*** stretches through ***to expect*** to ***anticipate / plan for / intend*** [that something will happen, or be true].

---

Note that...

> 2: *Harry **was thought to** become an earl*

...doesn't really make sense at the *semantic* level, but if we change ***become*** to plain ***be*** it would mean that (unspecified) people ***believed / were under the impression*** that Harry actually *was* an earl. Note that exactly the same substitution wouldn't make any difference to the meaning of the ***supposed*** version as given above.

---

EDIT: I just realized there *are* perfectly ordinary contexts where the superficially "unusual" syntactic structure in #2 above is unexceptional. For example...

> 3: [*Hay lying on the ground was thought to become poisonous*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EHArncKhX3oC&pg=PA3&dq=%22was%20thought%20to%20become%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiis7nnms7iAhW5A2MBHWWEDdkQ6AEIMDAB)
>    4: [*...men were thought to become wolves*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SaJdVmk_2oYC&pg=PT8&dq=%22were%20thought%20to%20become%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNkP71m87iAhUG_RQKHTtaAmIQ6AEISDAF)
>    5: [*...patients were thought to become unnecessarily institutionalized*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=u3X9EceB76cC&pg=PA57&dq=%22were%20thought%20to%20become%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNkP71m87iAhUG_RQKHTtaAmIQ6AEIXTAJ)
>    ...

So perhaps Harry was a fervent socialist who claimed that he always adopted a free "peasant" persona when playing online games set in medieval Arthurian England. Peasants would be at a disadvantage in those games, because they'd have limited resources, but players could *pay* for a more powerful persona (a squire or a knight, for example). Harry boasted that even though he could afford to pay, he was virtuously "handicapping" himself to show solidarity with the working classes throughout the ages. But some of his friends suspected Harry was lying, and that he *didn't* become a peasant in the virtual world. In fact, ***Harry was thought to become an earl*** (some thought maybe he even paid enough to become King Arthur himself! :)

> 

Comment: Verbs expressing likelihood are modals: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/modals-and-modality/modality-other-verbs Well explained as a shift in modality by Cerberus in ELU:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/why-do-we-say-was-supposed-to-for-should-have

Comment: Thanks for you reply:) Is there any chance for non-native speaker to understand ‘thought to be’ semantic inadequacy in this context? I mean, is there any rule or dirty tip that could be used to eliminate ‘thought’ option in that context?

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko Yes: He was supposed to be an earl=expected to be. He was thought to be an earl.=We were not sure that he was an earl at some point in the past. to be thought to be means: the speaker is not sure of whether the complement is in fact true.

Comment: It’s sinking in:) In a nutshell, ‘thought to be’ doesn’t have any future notion if compared with ‘supposed to be’. Am I right?

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko: There's a subtle difference between X being *thought to **be** Y* and *thought to **become** Y*. Approximately, the ***be*** version is either "present, here & now", or it's "timeless" (the belief is that X ***is*** Y). But the ***become*** version implies X ***isn't*** Y (usually, or currently), though it's believed it will be at some (future) time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're what I call a perfect teacher! You made it clear for me with your hillarious example:) I can't thank you enough. You contribute a lot to my love for StackExchange!

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko: Thank you for the kind words. You may have stirred up a bit of a hornet's nest regarding the question of whether this particular usage should be classified as "passive". I don't really think arguments about terminology should be important for most people using ELL, but I find it kinda flattering that retired linguistics professor John Lawler has decided to pitch in here. I look forward to chewing over his answer below (as soon as I've posted this comment), and I suspect that very likely I'll end up learning as much as you from this web page!

Answer (score 1):

Like *[be used to](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62252/15299), be supposed to* is an idiom that has become a fixed phrase, and in many speakers' minds and voices, single words -- *useta* and *sposta*, with their own individual and very idiomatic syntax.

This is new syntax. In both of these constructions, the question of whether it's passive or active is irrelevant, since that's entirely a matter of definition and metaphoric projection of "active" and "passive", neither of which is relevant to the grammar or meaning of the construction. That kind of pilpul can go on ad lib for years.

As for your exam question, *supposed to* (pronounced /'spostə/) is the correct answer because it is idiomatic, whereas *thought to* isn't. Both are grammatical, but exam questions rarely have anything to do with that.

Comment: As [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/) to my own question about this usage over on ELU some years ago points out, *there is a tendency in many languages for words to shift in meaning between **probability** and **desirability***. As I get older and more cynical, I find myself increasingly thinking that *deliberate **concealment / obfuscation** [of meaning]* can be a significant factor in how languages are used, and how they evolve. This principle seems particularly relevant to slang/cant dialects, as well as contexts involving expectations, desires, promises, etc.

Comment: "supposed to (pronounced /'spostə/)" While I do hear that pronunciation I think of it as careless, and I hear a fuller pronunciation  with three syllables and two distinct words more often.

Comment: Thank you a lot:) I really appreciate your help. That's very important for me to go deeper into the topic, so your reasoning and speculations are of a great value.

Answer (score -1):

"supposed to become" is correct, and as the answer by FumbleFingers explains, means "was intended to become".  However, the statement that  "This is a special use of the verb to suppose that only occurs in passive contexts" is not correct. It can be used in the active voice as well:

> - I am supposed to prepare the food before I pour the drinks.
> - You are supposed to enter the study only when requested.
> - Jane was supposed to have the analysis done by Thursday.
> - The company is supposed to mention your right to sue on every statement.

Comment: I disagree that your examples are somehow "active". They're all exactly the same passive structure (as regards the syntax and meaning of *[be] **supposed to***) as OP's and my own. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/81467/126) to an earlier question about the usage, which concedes immediately that ***supposed** is indeed a past participle, and **am supposed** is a **passive***. The fact that it's "counter-intuitive" to derive the idiomatic passive meaning from what (active) ***to suppose*** normally means just makes that an unhelpful approach for semantic deconstruction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I cannot agree that "I am supposed to" is a passive construction. The grammatical subject "I" is also the actor, which is about as clear a definition of an active construction as there is. That this may have arisen through a passive form, if it did, is not relevant, nor does "supposed" really **function** as a past participle in this form.

Comment: Concepts and terminologies change over time, and vary across communities, so we may effectively be arguing at the level of "You say tomato, I say potato" (or whatever). The remnants of the linguist in me today wants to see these things in terms of "agent" and "patient", but nobody thought like that 50 years ago when I actually studied linguistics. Whatever - I might ask what others think about this over on ELU tomorrow, just to see if there's anything like a consensus. (Which may or may not include me, and/or I might change my mind anyway, I dunno! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Fair enough. And I think we agree on the actual usage, even if we do not agree on the terminology. How to use English well matters more than whether we call something ;'active" or passive" although labels are needed for analysis.  I will be interested in any consensus that develops.

Comment: Okay, well we've tempted @JohnLawler out of "semi-retirement" to weigh in on this one, and I think I've seen enough now to conclude that there's little point in trying to shoehorn oddball usages like this into the standard terminological framework. But I'm still not clear as to why you think *your* examples could be classified as "active" and by implication OP's as "passive". Regardless of what we ***call*** it, what exactly ***is*** the difference? They look pretty much the same to me. Do you see a *syntactic* difference, or is it a matter of *semantics?*

Comment: The difference which seems significant to me is that the person who was required to **do** something serves as the grammatical subject (or more exactly the pronoun representing that person). Maybe that isn't grammatically significant.

Comment: I think I gotcha. So it's really a *semantic* distinction, whereby you'd say *I'm supposed to **be protected*** is effectively "passive", whereas *I'm supposed to **protect you*** is "active". Is that right?

Comment: Hmm. Put that way it sounds as if I am using the term "active" improperly, yet I don't see a hole in your argument. I will need to rethink this. I saw in some of the linked posts on EL a mention that "meant" can also carry a meaning of "duty". I have encountered this many times, but always in UK contexts. Do you think this is a US/UK difference?

Comment: I certainly never realized there was a US/UK split until now! But I've just been comparing US/UK corpuses in NGrams for ***you are meant to*** (and more casual ***you're meant to***). I have the distinct impression we Brits have adopted the usage earlier and more enthusiastically than you guys over the pond. And the meaning there is definitely controlled by this "active/passive" distinction (or whatever we call it). So ***I meant to go*** means I intended to go, but ***I am / I'm meant to go*** means I'm sposta go (me going is what's expected / intended, by circumstances or by unnamed others).